# php misinterpretation of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with a "Text" col which contains a javascript object like this:

```
{
    "description"       : "", 
    "title"             : " diagramm1",
    "xlabel"            : "Zeit",
    "ylabel"            : "",
    "ylabel1"           : "Anzahl Stabis aufgelegt",
    "ylabel2"           : "Anzahli.O.",
    "tablename"         : "edmat1",
    "xvaluecol"         : "timestamp",
    "y1valuecol"        : "EDMAT1Q001",
    "y2valuecol"        : "EDMAT1Q002",
    "showRangeSelector" : true,
    "divid"             : "diagramm1",
    "refreshtime"       : 30000
 }
```

If I get this out of the database with php it is interpreted as a php array. What can I do to force php to treat this like a string? Afterwards I want to give this javascript object to javascript.

Tried `json_encode` on php side and `JSON.parse` at Javascript side, there must be a other solution.

EDIT:

```
$db=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("visualization");
$anfrage="SELECT options FROM mat1 WHERE id=1";
$a=mysql_query($anfrage);
$b=mysql_fetch_row($a);
echo $b;
```

only have on row!

Comment: Can you show us the code which gets it from the db? Are you using PDO?

Comment: Forced it to an object (object)?

Comment: the database col options type is TEXT. the javascript object is stored exactly like in the post...

Comment: you have to do $b[0] to get the first element from the array, and this must be your JSON string

Comment: $result = (string) $b[0];   Does it help?

Comment: Yep I agree with Mirko, $db[0] should be exactly the JSON string you want. $b will per definition be an array.

Comment: Actually (string)$b[0] is not needed, because the only type of data, mysql returns, is STRING

Answer (score 0):

> If I get this out of the database with php it is interpreted as a php array. What can I do to force php to treat this like a string?

If you store it as a string, then it will stay a string. Even in JavaScript you have to parse it to have an object or an array.

You use mysql_fetch_row, that means you will have your row with your result in an indexed array.
As yoy selected only one column, your array will contain only one column too.
So your solution is (as said in comments) `$your_result = $db[0];`

Moreover, acording to the php doc I advise you to switch your mysql_ function to mysqli_ functions that are newer, more performant and which support newer version of Mysql SGBD.